# FIFO buffer: unable to assign to unresolved wires

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am making Verilog code for a FIFO buffer. I wrote the testbench, and it doesn't work and gets me these errors:

```
full Unable to assign to unresolved wires.
empty Unable to assign to unresolved wires.
DATAOUT Unable to assign to unresolved wires.
```

I simply can't solve these problems whatever I tried.

The code of the `fifo.v`:

```
module jFIFO(DATAOUT, full, empty, clock, reset, wn, rn, DATAIN);
  output reg [7:0] DATAOUT;
  output reg full, empty;
  input [7:0] DATAIN;
  input clock, reset, wn, rn;
  
  reg [2:0] state;
  reg [2:0] wptr, rptr;
  reg [7:0] memory [7:0];
  
  // FSM states
  localparam IDLE = 3'b000;
  localparam WRITE = 3'b001;
  localparam READ = 3'b010;
  
  always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (reset) begin
      memory[0] <= 0; memory[1] <= 0; memory[2] <= 0; memory[3] <= 0;
      memory[4] <= 0; memory[5] <= 0; memory[6] <= 0; memory[7] <= 0;
      DATAOUT <= 0; wptr <= 0; rptr <= 0; state <= IDLE;
      full <= 0; empty <= 1; // Initialize full and empty here
    end
    else begin
      case (state)
        IDLE: begin
          if (wn & !full)
            state <= WRITE;
          else if (rn & !empty)
            state <= READ;
        end
        
        WRITE: begin
          memory[wptr] <= DATAIN;
          wptr <= wptr + 1;
          state <= IDLE;
        end
        
        READ: begin
          DATAOUT <= memory[rptr];
          rptr <= rptr + 1;
          state <= IDLE;
        end
      endcase
      
      // Update full and empty based on state and wptr/rptr values
      full <= ((wptr == 3'b111) & (rptr == 3'b000)) ? 1 : 0;
      empty <= (wptr == rptr) ? 1 : 0;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

The testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module jFIFOTb;
  reg [7:0] DATAOUT;
  reg full, empty;
  reg clock, reset, wn, rn;
  reg [7:0] DATAIN;
  reg [2:0] state;

  jFIFO DUT(DATAOUT, full, empty, clock, reset, wn, rn, DATAIN);
initial begin 
clock = 0;
forever #1 clock = ~clock;
end 

initial begin 
$monitor ("[$t]\tstate = %b\tDATAIN = %b\tDATAOUT = %b\twn = %b\trn =%b\treset = %b",$time,state,DATAIN,DATAOUT,wn,rn,reset);
end
initial begin
    DATAIN = 8'd0;
    reset = 0;
   full = 1'b0;
   DATAOUT = 8'd0;
   empty = 1'b1;
    wn = 0; rn = 0;
state = 3'b000;
end

initial begin 
    // First write some data into the queue
    #5 wn = 1; rn = 0;
    #5 DATAIN = 8'd100;
    #5 DATAIN = 8'd150;
    #5 DATAIN = 8'd200;
    #5 DATAIN = 8'd40;
    #5 DATAIN = 8'd70;
    #5 DATAIN = 8'd65;
    #5 DATAIN = 8'd15;
    #5 DATAIN = 8'd55;
    // Now start reading and checking the values
    #5 wn = 0; rn = 1;
    #5 wn = 0; rn = 1;
    #5 wn = 0; rn = 1;
    #5 wn = 0; rn = 1;
    #5 wn = 0; rn = 1;
    #5 wn = 0; rn = 1;
    #5 wn = 0; rn = 1;
    #5 wn = 0; rn = 1;
    #5 $stop;
end
 
endmodule
```

Comment: In the testbench, DATAOUT, full, and empty should be declared as wires, not regs. No need to assign initial values for them.

Comment: @sharvian
it gives me false output
[$time] state = 000 DATAIN = 00000000 DATAOUT = xxxxxxxx wn = 0 rn = 0 reset = 0
and so on

Answer (score -1):

DATAOUT, full and empty are **outputs** of the *jFIFO* module.
Your testbench tries to write values into them (creating multiple drivers) here:

```
initial begin
    DATAIN = 8'd0;
    reset = 0;
   full = 1'b0; <<<<<<<<<<
   DATAOUT = 8'd0; <<<<<<<<<
   empty = 1'b1; <<<<<<<
    wn = 0; rn = 0;
state = 3'b000;
end
```

It makes no sense. Just remove those lines.

Comment: when i do this, i get an error "continuous assignment" in the clock definition in the initial block. so i changed it to always block. but it gives me wrong output. output should be like this: [0] state = 000 DATAIN = 00000000 DATAOUT = 00000000 wn = 0 rn =0 reset = 0
[10] state = 001 DATAIN = 01100100 DATAOUT = 00000000 wn = 1 rn =0 reset = 0

Comment: there is no 'continuous assignments' in your code sample. As for the wrong answer, you need to debug your model and ask a new question if debugging fails.